# In what model should I add the ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-models

I read the [documentation about many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-manytomany) and the [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). What I could not find is a hint on where to put the *ManyToManyField*. In my case I have an extended user model *Client* and a model *Pizza*. Every client may mark one or more pizzas as favourites. Those are my two models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #? favourite_pizza = models.ManyToManyField()

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #? favourite_pizza = models.ManyToManyField()
```

**In what model should I add the ManyToManyField?** Does it matter?

PS The important information is how many favourite pizzas a client has (and which). It is less important how many clients marked a pizza as a favourite (and who). Consequently I would chose to put the *ManyToManyField* in the *Client* class.

Comment: It does not matter. You can query both ways. I would put it in `Client` as a personal preference (I feel it is more readable that way). But there no right or wrong place.

Comment: If you would state that again as an answer, that would be great! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships):

> Generally, ManyToManyField instances should go in the object that’s going to be edited on a form.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it does not matter. The question is from which model-side you will query the database.