# Django ManyToManyField : how to choose its place?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have two possibilities concerning the `ManyToManyField` in django :

putting it in the "parent" class :

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    pass

class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name='group')
```

putting it in the "child" class

```
from django.db import models

class Group(models.Model):
    pass

class Person(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='members')
```

What is the difference between these two options ?
Is there a reason to privilege one over the other ?

Comment: Don't have an answer for why, but I would always go for the second option. Even django uses it that way https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups

Comment: in the example given [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields), they do through an other class with the first option.

Comment: Well there is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773890/in-what-model-should-i-add-the-manytomanyfield

Comment: Technically they are equivalent, the only difference is semantic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In what model should I add the ManyToManyField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773890/in-what-model-should-i-add-the-manytomanyfield)